# Create List of Time Series

Tags: c#

I need to create a time series with 200 observations of 10 MeasureTypes (1 to 10) and join everything in a list (using C# 7):

```
var a = Enumerable.Range(1, 200).Select(x => new Measure { MeasureTypeId = 1, Created = DateTime.Now.AddDays(x), Value = (Decimal)(80 * random.NextDouble() + 40) });

var b = Enumerable.Range(1, 200).Select(x => new Measure { MeasureTypeId = 2, Created = DateTime.Now.AddDays(x), Value = (Decimal)(20 * random.NextDouble() + 30) });

// Other measures

var result = a.Union(b).Union(c). ...
```

What changes from measure to measure is the MeasureId which is incremental and the parameters (80 and 40) to (20 and 30) to ...

Is there a way to simplify this code?

Comment: *..parameters (80 and 40) to (20 and 30) to..* - To what? what are the next values? how are they determined? how many additional measurements do you have?

Comment: I can have 20 to 40 measures ... The idea would maybe have a variable that holds the min and maximum value for each MeasureType and then build the timeseries with it ...

Comment: Which part of code you want to simplify? Generating of mock random data?

Comment: @mukh1n Yes. I would like to have a variable that holds the 2 parameters for each MeasureId and then build the time series based on that.

Comment: I think this would be a better question for the code review SE forum as you are not actually having any problems (according to your question statement). You should clarify what it is you are looking for though as this question is very vague (I still am unclear what you are trying to do or ask for).

Comment: Create type MeasurementType with fields Id, Param1, Param2. Then you can do generation of Measurements generic way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `for` loop with an array (or list) of tuples or a custom type to hold the parameters, like the following:

```
var result = Set.Empty; // Or whatever you use

Tuple<int, int>[] params = {
    new Tuple<int, int>(80, 40),
    new Tuple<int, int>(20, 30),
    // and so on
}

for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    result.Union(Enumerable.Range(1, 200).Select(x => new Measure { MeasureTypeId = i + 1, Created = DateTime.Now.AddDays(x), Value = (Decimal)(params[i].Item1 * random.NextDouble() + params[i].Item2) }));
}

// LINQ version
var result = Enumerable.Range(1, N).SelectMany(x => Enumerable.Range(1, 200), (t, n) => new Measure {
    MeasureTypeId = t,
    Created = DateTime.Now.AddDays(n),
    Value = (decimal)(params[t - 1].Item1 * random.NextDouble() + params[t - 1].Item2)
});
```

You can use C# 7's sugared tuple syntax if you want, I aren't that well versed with it yet.

If your parameters are part of a series, you can skip the tuples entirely.

LINQ version borrowed and modified from [@ChrisPickford's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43068173/4038191).

Comment: MeasureId must also change ... And would be possible to use Linq and not a loop? Just asking ...

Comment: @MiguelMoura edited my answer to include a LINQ version.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
var random = new Random();
int[] multipliers = { 80, 20, 30, 50 };
int[] add = { 40, 30, 10, 20 };
var result = Enumerable.Range(1,4).SelectMany(t => 
    Enumerable.Range(1, 200).Select(x => 
        new Measure { 
        MeasureTypeId = t, 
        Created = DateTime.Now.AddDays(x), 
        Value = (Decimal)(multipliers[t-1] * random.NextDouble() + add[t-1]) }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you are calculating `Measure.Value`, however you can use a `SelectMany` to effectively `CROSS JOIN` two enumerations together:

```
var result = Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
    .SelectMany(x => Enumerable.Range(1, 200), (t, n) => new Measure {
        MeasureId = ((t - 1) * 200) + n,
        MeasureTypeId = t,
        Created = DateTime.Now.AddDays(n),
        Value = (decimal)(80 * random.NextDouble() + 40) // Replace with your logic
    });
```

Comment: While this doesn't answer the question, I've used a modified version of your answer as an extension to my answer, and upvoted. If you want me to revert the edits, I can.

Comment: Updated with MeasureId

Answer (score 0):

```
  public class MeasurementType
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Parameter1 { get; set; }
    public int Parameter2 { get; set; }
  }

  public class Measurement
  {
    public int MeasureTypeId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
  }

  public class MeasurementGenerator
  {
    private List<MeasurementType> MeasurementTypes
    {
      get
      {
        return new List<MeasurementType>
        {
          new MeasurementType() {Id = 1, Parameter1 = 80, Parameter2 = 40},
          new MeasurementType() {Id = 2, Parameter1 = 20, Parameter2 = 30},
          new MeasurementType() {Id = 3, Parameter1 = 10, Parameter2 = 50},
          new MeasurementType() {Id = 4, Parameter1 = 15, Parameter2 = 60},
          //and so on
        };
      }
    }

    public List<Measurement> GenerateMeasurements(int type)
    {
      var result = new List<Measurement>();
      for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
      {
        var measurementType = MeasurementTypes.First(x => x.Id == type);
        result.Add(new Measurement { MeasureTypeId = type, Created = DateTime.Now.AddDays(i), Value = measurementType.Parameter1 * random.NextDouble() + measurementType.Parameter2 });
      }
      return result;
    }
  }
```

Comment: @ChrisPickford If you think that simple code is one-line code, you are wrong.

Comment: I do not, however your answer is much more convoluted than the original question.